# CarrierWave / Cloudinary give a url to upload image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

I'm moving from Paperclip to CarrierWave and Cloudinary and I want move all my previous images store on S3 to Cloudinary.

My current approach is by doing so:

```
my_model.cloudinary_logo = open(my_model.logo.url)
my_model.save
```

But this force my to download the file and then uploaded to cloudinary, can't I just give it the url instead?

Another approach is by doing:

```
cloudinary_uploaded_file = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(my_model.logo.url)
my_model.write_attribute :c_image, "v#{cloudinary_uploaded_file['version']}/#{cloudinary_uploaded_file['public_id']}.#{cloudinary_uploaded_file['format']}"
```

But that is a little hacky in my opinion...

Comment: Looking at their GitHub page it seems you just need to set the `attribute_name_here_url` on the model.

Comment: Where on the page did you find that?

Comment: There's an "Uploading files from a remote location" section.  https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Comment: Oh right! I'm gonna check that out, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned jcm in the comments, we can use: `remote_attribute_url`. Simple as that!
So the code becomes:

```
my_model.remote_c_image_url = my_model.logo.url
my_model.save
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to wait a little bit before doing it.

Comment: but how can we use it using carrierwave + cloudinary